# Using jquery append to add option values into a select element not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to dynamically populate a select element with names of items that are stored into an array.

For some reason it's not working and I'm not sure why.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <select class="select1">
    </select>
        and
    <select class="select2">
    </select>
</div>
```

Note that I'm using bootstrap for layout.

Here's the jquery I'm using to try and populate ".select1"

**JQUERY:**

```
select: function() {
    $.each(state.greens, function(index, value) {
        $(".select1").append("<option value =' " + index + " '>" + state.greens[index].name + "</option>");
    });
}
```

Note that the function 'select' is stored within an object called 'display'.

state.greens is the name of the array I'm trying to access.

So at the end of my html page I call display.select(); to call the function.

No error messages are showing up in the console.

Also, I saw this question:  [Appending options to select using jQuery doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926558/appending-options-to-select-using-jquery-doesnt-work)

but was looking for a jquery centric answer and this seems like it ought to work.

Comment: Is it possible state.greens is not within scope of your function? Try consoling state.greens.length on the first line of your function. I would also avoid naming your function 'select'.

Comment: Definitely your code works. See this https://fiddle.jshell.net/0z38v1bd/ ... as @RyanNeuffer said, make sure state.greens is in the same context of your select method

Comment: @RyanNeuffer - I followed your recommendation and the length of state.greens was 12.......which is what it should be.  Any ideas?

Comment: The code works: https://jsfiddle.net/h5kuhL6x/ so there's something else going on that's not reflected in your example/setup. Console out $(".select1").length and ensure it exists in the DOM when you are calling display.select();

Answer (score 3):

You can do in that way:

```
$.each(state.greens, function(index, value) {
    $('.select1').append($('<option>', {
        value: index ,
        text: state.greens[index].name
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you append you are basically adding to the .innerHTML value of a container. This works for most elements except for `<select>`. You'll have to add elements properly for the DOM to pick it up:

```
var select=document.getElementById('select1');
var option=document.createElement('option');
option.setAttribute('value','option1');
option.innerHTML='Option 1';
select.appendChild(option);
```