# How to populate a select with jQuery get, then set select's value?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use jQuery's get function to populate a select (based on results of a sql query in a CF component). Populating works fine, but then I want to make the correct option selected after the select has been populated. Tried using done(), but that doesn't seem to work. Example code:

```
function fChangeSelect() {
     var txOutcomeSelect = ('#someSelect');
     $.get("#request.webroot#cfc/assessment.cfc?method=getEncCatChildrenRemote&encCatIdList=" + encCatIdList,
                    function(jsonText){
                        var qryTxOutcomes = JSON.parse(jsonText);

                        //qryTxOutcomes is now an object with 2 arrays: COLUMNS and DATA.
                        //COLUMNS is an array of strings of the column names.
                        //DATA is an array of arrays, where each array is a row.
                        //Thus, every data cell is DATA[rownumber][columnnumber]


                        txOutcomeSelect.empty();
                        txOutcomeSelect.append('<option value="">--Select an Outcome--</option>');
                        $.each(qryTxOutcomes.DATA, function() {
                            txOutcomeSelect.append('<option value=' + $(this)[5] + '>' + $(this)[3] + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
    ).done(function(){
         txOutcomeSelect.val('123');//does nothing, because select isn't populated yet.
        alert('txOutcomeSelect should be populated by now, but its not. It only populated after I click OK on this alert.');
    });
}
```

(update) Apparently it has nothing to do with the timing of the ajax. For a test, I put in a button which displays an alert with the select's number of options. I waited for the page to load and the select to populate, then clicked the button, and the alert came back with "0". So even though the select is being populated with append(), and the options are visible on the screen, jQuery still thinks the select is empty.

Comment: Try putting the code that calls `.val()` in the same callback as the one that appends all the options, after the `$.each()` loop. I don't know if it's guaranteed which will run first when you use two completion functions like this.

Comment: I think I found the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31395944/using-jquery-append-to-add-option-values-into-a-select-element-not-working. Append() adds to the innerHTML of the select, but for the DOM to pick it up properly, it has to be done as demonstrated on this link.

Comment: You're missing `$` in here: `var txOutcomeSelect = ('#someSelect')` It should be `$('#someSelect')`. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that question is wrong. You don't have to do anything special to add options to a `<select>`.

Comment: Yeah, the missing '$' was just a copy error; the code works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, other than the jQuery get, I had to use plain old javascript to clear/populate/select options for the select, and now the select-option-after-ajax-runs functionality works.

I did end up having to use done() to ensure the proper option is selected only after the ajax is done. I also ended up having to pass an additional argument to indicate if the the function is being called because of a page reload, because this function is called both when the page loads and when the master select changes. When page loads, the select is populated based on the value of another "master" select, and I want the selected option to match what was pulled from the DB. When the master select changes, I want the options of the "sub" select to change, but don't want any option to be pre-selected.

So, my function(s) ended up looking like below. A little roundabout; I'm surprised jQuery hasn't been updated to make doing it this way unnecessary.

```
        //Using ajax to populate Treatment Outcome selects, based on selected Assessment Outcome

        function fChangeTxOutcome(sel, bLoading) {  
            var id = sel.prop('id');
            var idNum = id[id.length-1];
            var txOutcomeSelect = document.getElementById('txOutcomeSelect' + idNum);

            $.get("#request.webroot#cfc/assessment.cfc?method=getEncCatChildrenRemote",
                function(jsonText){
                    var qryTxOutcomes = JSON.parse(jsonText);

                    //qryTxOutcomes is now an object with 2 arrays: COLUMNS and DATA.
                    //COLUMNS is an array of strings of the column names.
                    //DATA is an array of arrays, where each array is a row.
                    //Thus, every data cell is DATA[rownumber][columnnumber]

                    //clear out any options first
                    for(var i=txOutcomeSelect.options.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                        txOutcomeSelect.remove(i);
                    }
                    var firstOption = document.createElement('option');
                    firstOption.setAttribute('value', '');
                    firstOption.innerHTML = '--Select an Option--';
                    txOutcomeSelect.appendChild(firstOption);

                    $.each(qryTxOutcomes.DATA, function() {
                        var thisOption = document.createElement('option');
                        thisOption.setAttribute('value', $(this)[5]);
                        thisOption.innerHTML = $(this)[3];
                        txOutcomeSelect.appendChild(thisOption);
                    });
                }
            ).done(function(){
                if (bLoading) {
                    fmakeTxOutcomeSelected(txOutcomeSelect);                    
                }
            })
        };

        function fmakeTxOutcomeSelected(sel){
                var id = sel.id;
                var idNum = id.charAt(id.length-1);
                var arrOutcomeIds = [];

                arrOutcomeIds[0] = '';
                arrOutcomeIds[1] = '#Get_cas.cEncOutcomeID#';
                arrOutcomeIds[2] = '#Get_cas.cEncOutcomeID2#';

                sel.value = arrOutcomeIds[idNum];
            }
```